# Save as Guest with IP and lat lng in Locations table and After User Registration associate user to location table permanently

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I created Location Table with IP, Lat , Lng and Address Columns for guest. My Goal is to save unknown visitor value in location Table with their unique system IP address. Once the visitor register and become permanent user I want that user associate with location table permanently. Later on he can change the location whenever he want.

is this better approach I am bit confuse about the logics please suggest how can I accomplish this task?

User Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->enum('role',['admin','seller','rider','customer'])->default('customer');
        $table->string('provider')->nullable();
        $table->string('provider_id')->nullable();
        $table->enum('status',['active','inactive'])->default('active');
        $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Guest Location Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('ip')->unique();
        $table->string('lat');
        $table->string('lng');
        $table->string('faddress'); 
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('SET NULL');           
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: it's a good approach, just save the locations in a separated table as you did and make sure to update it with the user_id if he register but make sure that `user_id` is nullable in locations table.

Comment: one confusion or scenario if user come as guest and not register from first IP then data will save location table. 
He change the location as well as connected with an other IP device this time he will register. then the old IP location will waste?